# Attributes handling in C++ Design

Tags: c++, oop, attributes

This is what troubles me: I have a hierarchy of classes with a set of attributes that either are mandatory or not. These classes are serialized into XML (or something else). The attributes which are mandatory should be serialized all the time, those that are not, should be serialized only if I specified them.

I am looking for a way which would automate this process as much as possible without having to specifically checking each of the attributes if they have set a value or not.

Here is an example:

```
 class Book
 {

     QString m_author;           // this is optional
     QString m_secondaryAuthor;  // this is optional
     QString m_title;            // this is mandatory

 public: 
     QString serializePlainText()
     {
         QString result = "Book:";
         result += m_title;
         if(m_author.length()) result+= " by "+m_author;
         if(m_SecondaryAuthor.length()) result+= " and "+m_SecondaryAuthor;
         return result;
     }

     void setTitle(const QString& title)
     {
         m_title = title;
     }

     void setAuthor(const QString& author)
     {
         m_author = author;
     }
 };
```

Of course, this is just a plain example, the real life is much more complicated, the class can have hundred of attributes. And here comes in the second part of the question: I need to be able to set the attributes in a more strict way, ie. without using a map in which I map to the string attribute the value, but more or less like in the example above (with setter functions `setTitle(const QString&)` ... etc....

Any fancy way of doing this considering:

1. without having to manually declare and check for all the attributes
2. having a nice looking and programmer friendly API?

I am more or less stuck with Qt, however this is not mandatory.

Thanks,
f.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve: you want to give a list of mandatory and optional attributes, and automatically generate getters/setters for these attributes, as well as serialization code? Is that right? Could you provide an example of what kind of code you'd like to have?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the preprocessor to generate code for you, you can rely on [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor). For instance, you could do something along these ways:

```
#define GET_TYPE( pair ) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( 2, 0, pair )
#define GET_NAME( pair ) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( 2, 1, pair )

#define DECLARE_MANDATORY( r, data, elem ) GET_TYPE( elem ) GET_NAME( elem );

#define DECLARE_MANDATORY_ATTRIBUTES( attributes ) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( DECLARE_MANDATORY, ~, attributes )

#define DECLARE_OPTIONAL( r, data, elem ) boost::optional< GET_TYPE( elem ) > GET_NAME( elem );

#define DECLARE_OPTIONAL_ATTRIBUTES( attributes ) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( DECLARE_OPTIONAL, ~, attributes )

#define MANDATORY_ACCESSORS( r, data, elem ) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT( void set_, GET_NAME( elem ) ) (GET_TYPE( elem ) const & value) { GET_NAME( elem ) = value; } \
    GET_TYPE( elem ) BOOST_PP_CAT( get_, GET_NAME( elem ) ) () const { return GET_NAME( elem ); }

#define DEFINE_MANDATORY_ACCESSORS( attributes ) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( MANDATORY_ACCESSORS, ~, attributes )

#define OPTIONAL_ACCESSORS( r, data, elem ) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT( void set_, GET_NAME( elem ) ) (GET_TYPE( elem ) const & value) { GET_NAME( elem ).reset(value); } \
    GET_TYPE( elem ) BOOST_PP_CAT( get_, GET_NAME( elem ) ) () const { return *GET_NAME( elem ); }

#define DEFINE_OPTIONAL_ACCESSORS( attributes ) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( OPTIONAL_ACCESSORS, ~, attributes )

class Book
{
    #define BOOK_MANDATORY_ATTRIBUTES ((std::string, title))
    #define BOOK_OPTIONAL_ATTRIBUTES ((std::string, author)) ((std::string, secondaryAuthor))

  public:

    DECLARE_MANDATORY_ATTRIBUTES( BOOK_MANDATORY_ATTRIBUTES )
    DECLARE_OPTIONAL_ATTRIBUTES( BOOK_OPTIONAL_ATTRIBUTES )

    DEFINE_MANDATORY_ACCESSORS( BOOK_MANDATORY_ATTRIBUTES )
    DEFINE_OPTIONAL_ACCESSORS( BOOK_OPTIONAL_ATTRIBUTES )
};

int main()
{
    Book b;
    b.set_title("H2G2");

    std::cout << b.get_title();

    b.set_author("Douglas Adams");
    std::cout << b.get_author();
}
```

You can create another macro to generate the code for your serialization function, leveraging the use of [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional] to test whether an optional attribute has been set or not.

If you don't want to do code generation, you won't be able to automatically obtain accessors for your attributes. However, the serialization aspect can be handled more classicaly, for instance by using a common base class for all your attributes. This way, you can store them in a container, and iterate over them to ask them to serialize themselves:

```
struct Attribute
{
    virtual QString serializePlainText() = 0;
};

// Generic attribute for the most common cases
template <typename T>
class MandatoryAttribute : public Attribute
{
    T value;

  public:

    std::string serializePlainText() 
    { 
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value);
    }
};

// Generic attribute for the most common cases
template <typename T>
class OptionalAttribute : public Attribute
{
    boost::optional<T> value;

  public:

    bool isSet() const { return value; }

    std::string serializePlainText() 
    { 
        return isSet() ? 
            boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value) :
            "";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So. My first thought is "use a nice dynamic language" but I guess that's not an option. I do have a few vague suggestions however.

1. Use a map. Maps can be iterated over, making your serialisation code substantially less painful. It also makes adding new attributes much easier.
2. Use a single getter and a single setter function, as that's simple simplest and neatest API for client code to call.
3. Keep a map of known attribute names and metadata values separately.

Upon a call to set, the requested attribute name can be looked up in your attribute metadata table. You can then perform any validations or transformations you'd like. I'm assuming that you don't need a set of unique and complex requirements for each attribute's structure here, of course... most attributes probably just need things like minimum or maximum length?

At serialisation time, you can iterate over your attribute metadata table, finding the names of all mandatory attributes, and looking them up in your attribute value table. After that, traverse your attribute value table, and serialise any remaining items.